# How I can call async method in different class?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have got this code:

```
public async Task DoRespond(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
        {
            System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket socket = context.WebSocket;
            while (true)
            {
                ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
                WebSocketReceiveResult result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
                if (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    string userMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, result.Count);
                    userMessage = "Message from client : " + userMessage;
                    buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userMessage));
                    await socket.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

I need to call this async method in different class in bool method (it is an NUnit framework)

```
protected override bool Test()
{
    Websocket ws = new Websocket();
    ws.ProcessRequest(context);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    logger.Write("Async method ");
    var task = Task.Run(DoRespond);
}
```

I need to call async Task method in this bool method. How i can do that ? I aslo need call a parametre AspNetWebSocketContext context.

Comment: You `await` it, just like you were doing in the first method.

Answer (score 1):

The `async..await` pattern is contagious and will spread thru your code base.

in order to call the `async` method, you need to `await` it in another `async` method

```
protected override async Task<bool> Test()
{
    using (Websocket ws = new Websocket()) // properly dispose of WebSocket
    {
        ws.ProcessRequest(context);
        await Task.Delay(1000); // notice the awaitable Delay replacing the blocking Sleep.
        logger.Write("Async method ");
        await DoRespond(context);
    }

    return true; // not sure where Boolean return value comes from as it wasn't in original method.
}
```

and, of course, whatever is calling `Test()` will get similar treatment.

**Edit after more information in comments**

The test method can be forced to wait for the `async` method to complete similar to this

```
protected override bool Test()
{
    using (Websocket ws = new Websocket()) // properly dispose of WebSocket
    {
        ws.ProcessRequest(context);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        logger.Write("Async method ");

        var task = DoRespond(context);
        task.Wait(); // wait for async method to complete

        // assert something?
    }

    return true; // not sure where Boolean return value comes from as it wasn't in original method.
}
```

However, do read up on asynchronous testing with NUnit since `async` test methods (like the first example) have been supported for several years.

For further reading, [Async Support in NUnit](http://simoneb.github.io/blog/2013/01/19/async-support-in-nunit/)

Comment: Thank You, but it is not fit to my case. I have this bool method to run all methods from 20 different classes mostly void, i cannot change override bool Test () to async.

Comment: you can use the methods and properties on `Task` to force an evaluation before continuing, `Task.Wait()` will possibly be of use to you since it synchronously waits for the task to complete.  However, be aware there are a few edge cases that can be difficult to debug.

Comment: if it isn't obvious, I can post an example of how it is used.

Comment: Yes, please put an example. Is it possible to call this async method without changing bool Test() ?